# Shutting down VM while inflating a layout containing RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-anr-dialog

I am trying to implement a `RecyclerView` in a fragment. But I am getting `shutting down vm` (app crashes) while trying to inflate a view in   `onCreateView` method is called.

fragment_test.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id = "@+id/todoRefreshContainer"
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

test.java

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        try
        {
            if (null == view)
            {
                view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test,
                                        container, false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return view;
    }
```

p.s. : I have added try catch block and still not getting what is going wrong. Removing recyclerview doesn't produce this erroor,

Comment: you are inflating a new view as well as calling `super`. correct it by inflating only one view.

Comment: @vipul_asri : No. it doesn't work. If this was the problem then it wouldn't have worked as well with the different layout.

Comment: what did `e.printStackTrace();` print in the logcat?

Comment: @donfuxx that exception is not caught and  that is why the error "Shutting down vm" comes. I think the exception occurs in baseclass

Answer (score 0):

Finally , I was able to resolve this. If someone faces this issue, please start a debugger and you will be able to see the full error.

This exception arises when you don't provide a `layoutManager` for the `RecyclerView`. Add the layout manager like this in `onCreateView` itself.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

I was doing the above in another thread (`AsyncTask`). It should be done on `UI thread` itself.